# If statement executing without meeting criteria

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have a strange problem! I have an IF statement that is executing as if the criteria for it were true, when the log output shows that it is not. 
Additionally, this only happens after a separate button is called first, not before.
So for example if I clicked on this button straight after running the program, it would work properly, as soon as I click the other button first and then click on the problematic one, it fails to do the IF statement properly.

As you can probably tell from the code below, the button should only light up if the criteria is true..

```
- (IBAction)affectedFather:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"status of autoDomOn %@",autoDomOn? @"On":@"Off");
    NSLog(@"status of xLinkedDomOn %@",xLinkDomOn? @"On":@"Off");

    if(autoDomOn==YES||xLinkDomOn==YES)
    {
     NSLog(@"father selected!");
     [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonOptionsHighlight.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      affectedMotherOut.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonOptions.png"];
      affectedParentsBoth.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonOptions.png"];
    }  
 NSLog(@"Do nothing!");
}
```

As the log output shows below, the IF statement should not be met and the button should not change to lit up... however it does.

```
2013-03-07 06:55:41.858 TCGA beta[6134:c07] status of xLinkedDomOn Off
2013-03-07 06:55:41.859 TCGA beta[6134:c07] Do nothing!
```

To try to avoid spamming too much code on this question I won't paste the other method, but really I'm trying to understand if there is there any reason that an if statement such as the one above would ignore the conditions?

I have been through the other method to rule out any parenthesis errors or memory location errors which there seems to be none. Happy to provide more information on request.

Thank you in advance for any advice you can offer!

Kind Regards, 
Sam

Comment: Did you mean `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: is ur tag autoDomOn & xLinkDomOn of type BOOL?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, || is correct as either statement can be TRUE. 
autoDomOn and xLinkDomOn are both 'bool'

Comment: Does just the button change, or do the `affectedX` image views change too?

Comment: you didn't post the log status for autoDomOn, may be it is On and thats why condition is being true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As H2CO3 already hinted, from the information you are providing the conditions may still be met (if autoDomOn is YES), so you might want to switch to && instead of ||.

If that's not the case make sure that both vars are not somehow changed or even released and the memory overwritten in your other code - that way you'd access the right memory location but it'd be filled with stuff from your other code causing weird behavior.

Comment: Apologies for not including the first condition, that was a copy and paste error and the conditions where definitely not met... 
I have managed to get around the problem by adding an else statement to ensure the button is set to off.. 

`code`        else
`code`        {
`code`         NSLog(@"Do nothing!");       
`code`    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonOptions.png"]`code` forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
`code`        }

Thank you for the suggestion Beegz, I think there must be something strange with the memory allocation going on, but I can't find it yet.